# Double sided bar chart?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, bar-chart

Am new to coreplot framework, rite now am working in barchart model and got some idea bt now i want to do double sided barChart (i need y axis both left and right corner)

OtherWise i need to move this following range value for y coordinate when i move over the different x position on the graph....

```
      plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPDecimalFromInteger(100)];
plotSpace.yRange =plotSpace.globalYRange;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many axes as you need. If you want both y-axes to have the same scale, you can use a single plot space. See the Mac version of CPTestApp for an example of adding a third axis to the graph.